# How to stop CSS rotation animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the css animation from the wheel whee2 car and track and make all of them to stop. Currently my track is translation in x direction and wheels are rotating in their own axis.

In simple words I want to remove the keyframes while I click somewhere, for this I can make a button with onclick property but it is not helping me enough.

**HTML Code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Car Animation and Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="sky">
        <div class="trees">

        </div>
        <div class="track">

        </div>
        <div class="car">
            <div class="wheel wheel1">
                <img src="car_wheel_left.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="wheel wheel2">
                <img src="car_wheel_right.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.sky{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
}
body{
overflow: hidden;
animation:shakeBody  linear 6s infinite;
}
.trees{
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(trees.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: -174px;
}
.track{
height: 30vh;
width: 800vw;
background-image: url(track.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
position: absolute;
top: 70vh;
animation: carMove linear 6s infinite;
}
.car{
height: 100px;
width: 319px;
background-image: url(car_body.png);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 66vh;
left: 75vh;
animation:shake  linear 6s infinite;
}
.wheel1 img{
width: 77px;
position: relative;
top: 39px;
left: 39px;
animation: wheelRotation linear .6s infinite;
}
.wheel2 img{
width: 77px;
position: relative;
top: -42px;
left: 215px;
animation: wheelRotation linear .6s infinite;
}
@keyframes wheelRotation{
100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
@keyframes carMove{
100%{
    transform: translateX(-500vw);
}
}

@keyframes shake{
0%{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
50%{
    transform: translateY(5px);
}
100%{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
}
@keyframes shakeBody{
0%{
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
50%{
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
100%{
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var audio=document.createElement('audio')
audio.setAttribute('src','sound.mp3')
audio.loop=true;
audio.play();
```

Comment: What you posted is not enough to repro, which means there are `0` chances that someone could answer your question. Please provide a [mcve] so we could understand what you're asking. Basically, we're missing the images. You either upload them somewhere and use those links or you could use codesandbox.io (or similar) to create a multi-file snippet.

Comment: Remove the class(s) with animations from the car element when you want to stop animating and add it when you want the animation to continue

Comment: It appears you have taken the code [from here](https://github.com/patelrohan750/caranimated.github.io) and are asking for it to be modified, but you have made no attempt of your own to achieve the desired result. This is against [SO] guidelines. It translates into requesting free coding services, which is *off-topic* here, for obvious reasons. Please make at least one decent attempt at achieving the desired result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request to modify open-source code without any research or coding effort on the part of the asker. In current form, it is a question asked by someone who did not demonstrate any coding abilities or intent, which makes their question *off-topic* here.

Comment: sir I  am a learner and believe me I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pause wheel animation when clicking, this might be helpful:

```
let wheels = document.getElementsByClassName('wheel');
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wheels[0].style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  wheels[1].style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

sir I has done this but when i am doing console.log(tr) it is printing null

```
let wheels = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
let tr =     document.getElementsByClassName('track');
let cr= document.getElementsByClassName(".car")
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
console.log(tr);
console.log(cr);
wheels[0].style.animationPlayState='paused';
wheels[1].style.animationPlayState='paused';
})
```